# How do I dynamically hide image in tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a tableView bound to a source in the ViewModel and how I want an image of the cell to be either hidden or visible based on a property in the ViewModel.

I had heard that I can use a visibility converter, but I have no idea how it would work.

I have a list of Events for the source and I also have a CurrentEvent property on the source. I want to show the image if the event used for the cell is the same for the CurrentEvent.

(I'm hoping I have the tableView bound correctly... completely new to Xamarin and MVVMCross)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    var source = new MvxStandardTableViewSource (TableView, "TextLabel EventName;");
    TableView.Source = source;

    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SelectEventViewController, EventsViewModel> ();

    set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.Events);
    set.Apply();

    this.CreateBinding(source).For(s => s.SelectionChangedCommand).To<EventsListingViewModel>(vm => vm.SelectEvent(vm.Events[TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow.Row])).Apply();

// hide "SuccessImage" if not same event... how to apply bidning?
//              .Bind(field)
//              .For("Visibility")
//              .To(vm => vm.VMProperty)
//              .WithConversion("Visibility");

    TableView.ReloadData();
}
```

How do I apply a visibility conversion binding to dynamically hide or show the image in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

The value converter you reference in your question is an mvvmcross plugin.  You can install it as a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Visibility/).

The [MvvmCross value converters wiki page](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters) has more info about using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it at the cell level. Here is an example that I do:

```
this.DelayBind(() =>
    {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyPlayersCell, PlayerViewModelWrapper>();

        set.Bind(_rowId).To(vm => vm.RowItem.RowId);
        set.Bind(_teamLogo).To(vm => vm.RowItem.Team.TeamId).WithConversion("TeamLogoImage");
        set.Bind(_teamLogo).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.RowItem.CanDisplayLogo).WithConversion("Visibility");
        set.Bind(_teamCode).To(vm => vm.RowItem.Team.TeamCode);
        set.Bind(_playerName).For(l => l.Text).SourceDescribed("IsCaptain(RowItem.PlayerName, RowItem.IsCaptain)");

        set.Apply();
    });
```